# Why gcc linker does not see my destructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I am trying to compile wkhtmltopdf-qt on a Linux machine following the instructions from https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation.

Now I am stuck with linker refusing to link. It prints several errors, but the one that caught my eyes is this:

```
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a(AccessibilityRenderObject.o): In function `WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()':
AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp:(.text._ZN7WebCore25AccessibilityRenderObjectD0Ev+0x5): undefined reference to `WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()'
```

This is strange to say the least. First, because the linker claims that the destructor attempts to reference itself and next - because it fails to do so! Crazy stuff...
Anyway, everything seems to be defined. Please, observe:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-245-78-162:~$ nm --defined-only -C -A /home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a | grep ~AccessibilityRenderObject
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a:AccessibilityRenderObject.o:0000000000000000 T WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a:AccessibilityRenderObject.o:0000000000000000 T WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a:AccessibilityRenderObject.o:0000000000000000 T WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()
ubuntu@ip-10-245-78-162:~/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/accessibility$
```

Next, in the file AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp:

```
#include <wtf/unicode/CharacterNames.h>

using namespace std;

namespace WebCore {

using namespace HTMLNames;

AccessibilityRenderObject::AccessibilityRenderObject(RenderObject* renderer)
    : AccessibilityObject()
    , m_renderer(renderer)
    , m_ariaRole(UnknownRole)
    , m_childrenDirty(false)
    , m_roleForMSAA(UnknownRole)
{
    m_role = determineAccessibilityRole();

#ifndef NDEBUG
    m_renderer->setHasAXObject(true);
#endif
}

AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()
{
    ASSERT(isDetached());
}
```

So, the destructor is defined just fine. But I went even further - I compiled AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp again, this time stopping at the preprocessor. Sure as hell the destructor is there:

```
class AccessibilityRenderObject : public AccessibilityObject {
protected:
    AccessibilityRenderObject(RenderObject*);
public:
    static PassRefPtr<AccessibilityRenderObject> create(RenderObject*);
    virtual ~AccessibilityRenderObject();
.
.
.
AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()
{
    ((void)0);
}
```

The compilation line used to compile that file (as well as many others) is this:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -Wall -Wextra -Wreturn-type -fno-strict-aliasing -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts -Wformat-security -Wreturn-type -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-switch -Wno-switch-enum -Wundef -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wno-c++0x-compat -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O2 -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG -DBUILDING_QT__=1 -DNDEBUG -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DENABLE_XSLT=0 -DENABLE_WEB_TIMING=0 -DENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_DEBUGGER=1 -DENABLE_DATABASE=1 -DENABLE_EVENTSOURCE=1 -DENABLE_OFFLINE_WEB_APPLICATIONS=1 -DENABLE_DOM_STORAGE=1 -DENABLE_ICONDATABASE=1 -DENABLE_CHANNEL_MESSAGING=1 -DENABLE_DIRECTORY_UPLOAD=0 -DENABLE_FILE_SYSTEM=0 -DENABLE_QUOTA=0 -DENABLE_SQLITE=1 -DENABLE_DASHBOARD_SUPPORT=0 -DENABLE_FILTERS=1 -DENABLE_XPATH=1 -DENABLE_WCSS=0 -DENABLE_SHARED_WORKERS=1 -DENABLE_WORKERS=1 -DENABLE_XHTMLMP=0 -DENABLE_DETAILS=1 -DENABLE_METER_TAG=1 -DENABLE_PROGRESS_TAG=1 -DENABLE_BLOB=1 -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS=1 -DENABLE_INPUT_SPEECH=0 -DENABLE_INSPECTOR=1 -DENABLE_3D_RENDERING=1 -DENABLE_WEB_AUDIO=0 -DENABLE_WEBGL=0 -DENABLE_MEDIA_STATISTICS=0 -DENABLE_VIDEO_TRACK=0 -DENABLE_TOUCH_ICON_LOADING=0 -DENABLE_ANIMATION_API=0 -DENABLE_SVG=1 -DENABLE_SVG_FONTS=1 -DENABLE_SVG_FOREIGN_OBJECT=1 -DENABLE_SVG_ANIMATION=1 -DENABLE_SVG_AS_IMAGE=1 -DENABLE_SVG_USE=1 -DENABLE_DATALIST=1 -DENABLE_TILED_BACKING_STORE=1 -DENABLE_NETSCAPE_PLUGIN_API=1 -DENABLE_WEB_SOCKETS=1 -DWTF_USE_QT_BEARER=1 -DENABLE_TOUCH_EVENTS=1 -DENABLE_VIDEO=0 -DENABLE_VIDEO=0 -DSQLITE_CORE -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPLETE -DXP_UNIX -DENABLE_NETSCAPE_PLUGIN_METADATA_CACHE=1 -DBUILDING_JavaScriptCore -DBUILDING_WTF -DBUILDING_WEBKIT -DQT_MAKEDLL -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../../../../../include/QtCore -I../../../../../include/QtNetwork -I../../../../../include/QtGui -I../../../../../include -I../JavaScriptCore -I../../Source -I../ThirdParty -I../JavaScriptCore/assembler -I../JavaScriptCore/bytecode -I../JavaScriptCore/bytecompiler -I../JavaScriptCore/heap -I../JavaScriptCore/dfg -I../JavaScriptCore/debugger -I../JavaScriptCore/interpreter -I../JavaScriptCore/jit -I../JavaScriptCore/parser -I../JavaScriptCore/profiler -I../JavaScriptCore/runtime -I../JavaScriptCore/wtf -I../JavaScriptCore/wtf/gobject -I/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/symbian -I../JavaScriptCore/wtf/unicode -I../JavaScriptCore/yarr -I../JavaScriptCore/API -I../JavaScriptCore/ForwardingHeaders -I../JavaScriptCore/generated -Ibridge/qt -Ipage/qt -Iplatform/graphics/qt -Iplatform/network/qt -Iplatform/qt -I../WebKit/qt/Api -I../WebKit/qt/WebCoreSupport -I. -Iaccessibility -Ibindings -Ibindings/generic -Ibridge -Icss -Idom -Idom/default -Iediting -Ifileapi -Ihistory -Ihtml -Ihtml/canvas -Ihtml/parser -Ihtml/shadow -Iinspector -Iloader -Iloader/appcache -Iloader/archive -Iloader/cache -Iloader/icon -Imathml -Inotifications -Ipage -Ipage/animation -Iplatform -Iplatform/animation -Iplatform/audio -Iplatform/graphics -Iplatform/graphics/filters -Iplatform/graphics/filters/arm -Iplatform/graphics/texmap -Iplatform/graphics/transforms -Iplatform/image-decoders -Iplatform/leveldb -Iplatform/mock -Iplatform/network -Iplatform/sql -Iplatform/text -Iplatform/text/transcoder -Iplugins -Irendering -Irendering/mathml -Irendering/style -Irendering/svg -Istorage -Isvg -Isvg/animation -Isvg/graphics -Isvg/graphics/filters -Isvg/properties -Itesting -Iwebaudio -Iwebsockets -I/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/wml -Iworkers -Ixml -Ibridge/jsc -Ibindings/js -I/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/bindings/js/specialization -Ibridge/c -Itesting/js -Igenerated -I../../Source -I../../include -I../include/QtWebKit -I../include -I../../../sqlite -I/usr/X11R6/include -I.moc/release-static -o .obj/release-static/AccessibilityRenderObject.o accessibility/AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp
```

Finally, the linker command line that fails is this:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/lib -Wl,-rpa
th,/home/ubuntu/wkqt/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/wkqt/lib -o tst_qwebframe .obj/release-static/tst_qwebframe.o .obj/release-static/qrc_tst_qweb
frame.o    -L/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib -lQtWebKit -L../../WebCore/release -L../../Ja
vaScriptCore/release -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -Wl,--start-group -lwebcore -lQtWebKit -Wl,--end-group -ljscore -lQtTest -lQtGui -lXrender -lXext -lX11
 -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lm -ldl -lrt -lpthread -lXrender -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

And all the linker errors referring to the aforementioned destructor are:

```
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a(AccessibilityRenderObject.o): In function `WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()':
AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp:(.text._ZN7WebCore25AccessibilityRenderObjectD2Ev+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject'
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a(AccessibilityRenderObject.o): In function `WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()':
AccessibilityRenderObject.cpp:(.text._ZN7WebCore25AccessibilityRenderObjectD0Ev+0x5): undefined reference to `WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject::~AccessibilityRenderObject()'
```

There are many suspicious linker errors, like:

```
/home/ubuntu/wkhtmltopdf-qt/lib/libwebcore.a(AccessibilityMenuList.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN7WebCore21AccessibilityMenuListE[typeinfo for WebCore:
:AccessibilityMenuList]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for WebCore::AccessibilityRenderObject'
```

But as far as I can see all the virtual functions are properly declared and defined and no makefile in all of the source tree mentions **rtti** at all.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Any difference if you add `-Wl,--gc-sections` to the linker command?

Comment: It is magic! It worked! Please, package it as a reply and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compilation command includes the options: `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` (documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)). `-ffunction-sections` puts each function in its own section of the object file, rather than simply placing them all in a single `.text` section. Similarly, `-fdata-sections` applies to global / static data.

The idea is that, by specifying `--gc-sections` ([garbage collection of unused input sections](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)), the linker can discard 'unreachable' sections before coalescing them into the final `.text` section of the binary. In short, to reduce code size without using separate compilation units for each function.

So that was the hunch. I would have expected it to work without the `--gc-sections` option regardless. Obviously there would be no benefit, since nothing gets discarded. Why does it fail?

When a destructor is implemented, the C++ ABI used by gcc, clang, etc., typically generates 3 destructor variants, ending with: `D0Ev`, `D1Ev`, `D2Ev`, as well as `vtable` and `typeinfo` data for that class. My guess is that these separate sections are not being coalesced correctly. Whether this is a bug, or a limitation of the linker (or link spec), I don't know.

---

This is also useless when building *shared* libraries, since there's no way of knowing in advance which symbols will be used. The compiler is invoked with `-fPIC`, which should be ok, since the objects are simply being archived. The `-fvisibility` options might be complicating the issue, however.